# User customizable backgrounds in Rails 3 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are looking to implement User customizable backgrounds in our Rails 3 App. We want to add this facet to the settings page, and from there allow users to upload a JPEG or whatever image file extension it may be, and then make sure it is tiled to fit each Browser window.

How should we go about implementing something like this?

If including code from our repo would assist in gathering a solution, definitely let me know.

Thank you all for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a get request from javascript for a rails resource that is said image and add this as the background-image() for the body.  To get the non-public image, this should be useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8313398/1040358.  To modify the css, this should be useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/253710/1040358.  Good luck! :)